# "callback" is not called in "getAttachmentContentAsync"

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook web addin.
I'm trying to get the attachment content with "getAttachmentContentAsync" but the callback is not called.

```
var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

function getAttachment(event){
    mailboxItem.getAttachmentsAsync({asyncContext: event}, callback);
}

function callback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.value.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < asyncResult.value.length; i++) {
            mailboxItem.getAttachmentContentAsync(asyncResult.value[i].id, function (result) {
                if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    console.log("Call returned success!");
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result.error);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting `function (result){}` to be called.